# Detaching from inside screen. ^a, ad doesnt work

Tags: gnu-screen, detach

Firstly, I hope this is the right place for this question. 
I have an odd problem with screen detaching. I can detach from most every screen I create, except one I am using to host a minecraft server.

When I hit control A D, all I get is another '>' symbol.

I get the same if i Hit control D.

I am doing the same thing that works on other screens, could this one be different somehow?

Comment: Refer to this, might help. [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012530/screen-not-detaching-with-ctrla-d#new-answer?newreg=f0a0ae2b8b9e4b4dbbc3b2622157e1dc)

Answer (score -3):

Ok, heres watcha wanna do. When you log into your unix system you get sent to the main screen. (The screen you first see) what you want to do, is type "screen". This will make you a new screen session. Now in this new screen session, start up your server. Once its started you can now CTRL+A D out of it, and it will take you to the main screen. I had this same exact problem. You NEED to have at least 2 screens to be able to do CTRL+A D.